# Where to start when proving correctness of algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I have just begun going through the algorithm design manual and am finding it difficult to grasp how to prove the correctness of algorithms. Can someone please help me by explaining the example question I have provided.

Prove the correctness of the following recursive algorithm to multiply two
natural numbers, for all integer constants c ≥ 2.

```
function multiply(y,z)
comment Return the product yz.
1. if z = 0 then return(0) else
2. return(multiply(cy, z/c) + y · (z mod c))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's formally state what we're trying to prove:

```
For all integers y, z, we have multiply(y, z) = y · z.
```

For recursive algorithms, we usually want an induction proof. This requires us to select an induction quantity, which should decrease on every recursive call. Here, we can use `|z|`. The inductive proposition is

```
For all integers k ≥ 0, for all integers y, z such that |z| = k,
  we have multiply(y, z) = y · z.
```

The base case is when `|z| = 0`. This implies that `z = 0`, and we verify that `multiply(y, z) = 0` (the `if` is taken) and `y · z = y · 0 = 0`.

The inductive cases are when `|z| > 0`. The `else` is taken, and since `c ≥ 2`, we know that `|trunc(z / c)| < |z|` and hence, by the inductive hypothesis, `multiply(c · y, trunc(z / c)) = c · y · trunc(z / c)`. The return value is thus

```
  c · y · trunc(z / c) + y · (z mod c)
= y · (c · trunc(z / c) + c · (z / c - trunc(z / c)))
= y · (c · z / c)
= y · z,
```

as required.

Comment: One of these moments where I look at a wall of text and I feel like an ape

Comment: How did you get the `c · (z / c - trunc(z / c)))` part?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It equals `z mod c` -- we divide, subtract the integer part of the quotient from itself, and multiply by `c` to get the remainder.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat What happened to the `y` in `y · (z mod c)`

Comment: @L.Norman Factored out. The entire expression after y . is in parens.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Ahh I needed to write out the intermediate step for myself to see, which would be: `y · (c · trunc(z/c)) + y · (c · (z / c - trunc(z / c)))` Thanks.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Can you clarify how the inductive hypothesis is used to conclude that `multiply(c · y, trunc(z / c)) = c · y · floor(z / c)`?

Comment: @WestonSankey thinko, I meant `trunc`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I figured that. My confusion is around how the inductive hypothesis is used to determine the equality of those equations.

Comment: @WestonSankey we're using [strong induction](https://brilliant.org/wiki/strong-induction/), so the inductive hypothesis is that `multiply(y, z') = y · z'` for all `y` and all `z'` such that `|z'| < |z|`. The assumption `c ≥ 2` is needed to ensure that `|trunc(z / c)| < |z|`.

Answer (score 2):

**By recursion on z.**

We suppose it is true for every z < K then, it is true for K.

It is true if z=0 : multiply(y,z)=0 (rule 1).

**Then it will be true for every K.**

**Case 1: z< c**

then z/c =0, z%c=z

then multiply(y,z)=multiply(cy, z/c) + y · (z mod c)) (rule 2).

= multiply(cy, 0) + y · z = 0 + y . z **= y . z  TRUE**

**Case 2: z>=c**

then z/c < z (because c>=2)

then multiply(y,z)=multiply(cy, z/c) + y · (z mod c)) (rule 2).

= cy . (z/c) + y . (z mod c) (RECURSION)

= y . (c . (z/c) + z mod c)

but c . (z/c) + z mod c = z  (definition of mod)

**then multiply(y,z)= y . z It is done.**

Comment: How is c*(z/c) + z mod c = z? Let c = 3 and z = 7 and you get 8 ≠ z.

Comment: @bmay2 - 7/3 = 2 => 3*(7/3) = 6 ,  7 mod 3 = 1 , => 6+1=7